# Ruby - Cannot perform calculations with array integers

Tags: ruby

I'll preface by telling you I'm a beginner. I'm trying to build a simple Ruby app that will calculate debt payments. It is simply a command line program for now.

The program starts off asking the name of your debt list (via debt_list_name method) and sets up a hash with keys of the user input list name and an array to hold information passed to it via the add_debt_item method.

The method, payment_schedule, is where I'm getting errors. The error is no implicit conversion of string to integer. I'm stumped by this because in the add_debt_item method, the user inputs are captured with a to_i method.

How I'm expecting that method to behave is to iterate through each hash of debt. For each debt, the output should account for the balance, subtract the min_payment from the balance and continue looping through that calculation until the balance reaches zero. I'm not sure a case statement will work for that but it's the most recent idea I've tried to solve this current error.

Should look like this for a balance of 500 and min payment of 100:

```
Payment 1: 100
Payment 2: 100
Payment 3: 100
Payment 4: 100
Payment 5: 100
```

I'm up for some critique but please bear with my novice understanding. Thanks for any/all assistance!

```
class Ds

def initialize
  @debts = []
end

def debt_list_name
  print "What is the name of your Debt List? "
  name = gets.chomp.capitalize
  @debt_list = {"name" => name, "debts" => @debts }
end

def ask
  loop do
    print "Would you like to add a debt to your snowball? (y/n) "
    answer = gets.chomp.downcase.to_s
    if answer == "n"
      break
    elsif answer == "y"
      add_debt_item()
    else answer != "y" || answer != "n"
      puts "Please type y or n"
    end
  end
end

def add_debt_item()
  print "What is the name of your source of debt? "
  institution = gets.chomp.capitalize
  print "What is the balance of #{institution}? "
  balance = gets.chomp.to_i
  print "What is your current minimum payment for #{institution}? "
  min_payment = gets.chomp.to_i

  hash = {"institution" => institution, "balance" => balance.to_i, "min_payment" => min_payment.to_i}
  @debts.push(hash)

end

def print_debt_list(debt_list)
  puts "Debt list: " + debt_list['name']
  puts "Institution" + "\t\t" + "Balance" + "\t\t" + "Minimum Payment"
  puts "-"*60
  debt_list["debts"].each do |debt|
    puts debt["institution"] + "\t"*3 + debt["balance"].to_s + "\t"*2 + debt["min_payment"].to_s
  end
end

def payment_schedule(debt_list)
  balance = debt_list["balance"].to_i
  min_payment = debt_list["min_payment"].to_i
  debt_list["debts"].each do |debt|
    loop do
      #if debt["balance"].to_i - debt["min_payment"].to_i > debt["min_payment"].to_i
        i ||= 1
        case balance <= min_payment
        when true
          puts "Payment: #{i}: " + balance
          break
        when false
          puts "Payment: #{i}: " + min_payment
          balance -= min_payment
          i += 1
        end
      #elsif debt["balance"].to_i - debt["min_payment"].to_i < debt["min_payment"].to_i
    end
  end
end


# instantiate class
ds = Ds.new
# sets up the debt list
debt_list = ds.debt_list_name
# input to ask user what debts they'd like to add
ds.ask
# prints out the contents of the debt list
ds.print_debt_list(debt_list)
# prints out the payment schedule
ds.payment_schedule(debt_list)


# end class
end
```

Comment: What is the line that fails with that error?

Comment: :57:in `block (2 levels) in payment_schedule': undefined method `<=' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

case balance <= min_payment

Comment: Sorry, had to edit the code. There should've been a to_i method after the balance and min_payment variable declarations. the error is now correct and on line 59 (puts "Payment: #{i}: " + balance)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to print to console a sample `debt_list`:

```
p ds.debt_list
```

Then, copy and paste it into a var in a separate file. Work on it to write the method you need. So you don't need to run the full app (via terminal). You can run and debug just directly in your favorite code editor, in Sublime `cmd + B`.

Lets say you printed this list, which is a hash:

```
debt_list = {"name"=>"ListName", "debts"=>[{"institution"=>"A", "balance"=>1005, "min_payment"=>100}, {"institution"=>"B", "balance"=>5000, "min_payment"=>500}]}
```

Work on it stand alone: just for example, one approach could be:

```
debt_list["debts"].each do |debt|
  puts "Payment schedule for #{debt["institution"]}"
  balance, min_payment = debt["balance"], debt["min_payment"]
  puts "#{balance} - #{min_payment}"
  num_payments = balance / min_payment
  last_payment = balance % min_payment # its the remainder
  num_payments.times do |n|
    puts "Payment #{n + 1}: #{min_payment}"
  end
    puts "Payment #{num_payments + 1}: #{last_payment}" unless last_payment == 0
end
```

Once it works as you expect, wrap it in your class method and test the full app.

**EDIT ---- Debugging your code**

This is your code running the debt_list as explained above. Explanations as comments.

```
def payment_schedule(debt_list)
  # balance = debt_list["balance"].to_i # this hash key does not exist at first level
  # min_payment = debt_list["min_payment"].to_i # this hash key does not exist at first level
  debt_list["debts"].each do |debt|
    balance = debt["balance"] # place assignement inside the each loop, here the hsh key exists -- add .to_i in case not already done in gets
    min_payment = debt["min_payment"] # place assignement inside the each loop, here the hsh key exists -- add .to_i in case not already done in gets
    puts "---- balance: #{balance} ---- min_payment: #{min_payment}" # added this line just as header
    i = 1 # i must be assigned outside the loop or it is restored each time
    loop do
      case balance <= min_payment
      when true
        puts "Payment: #{i}: " + balance.to_s # needs to convert balance to string, like this, or intrpolate
        break
      when false
        puts "Payment: #{i}: #{min_payment}" # needs to convert min_payment to string or interpolate, like this
        balance -= min_payment
        i += 1
      end
    end
  end
end

payment_schedule(debt_list)
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Any idea why my code is failing though? I'd like to learn from my mistake.

Comment: @ChristopherPhillips, of course, I made an edit with the debug of your code. Hope this helps you. Get back for any question.

Comment: Many thanks! I upvoted but because of my low rank here, it's not showing.